# checkbox with Multi Login page

Tags: c#

**hi guys i'm trying to build a simple multi login page with a checkbox but i couldn't make it work please see the coding below and help me out on where are my mistakes i appreciate it **

the error message that i have "" 'Log_in' does not contain a definition for 'checkbox1_Checked' and no extension method 'checkbox1_Checked' accepting a first argument of type 'Log_in' could be found ""

```
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = Othman\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog =Log-In; Integrated Security = True");

        try
        {
            if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlCon.Open();
                string query = "SELECT count (1) FROM Login WHERE Username=@Username AND password=@password";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
            if (count == 1)
            {
                if  ((bool)checkbox1.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    query = "SELECT usertype FROM Login WHERE Username=@Username AND password=@password AND usertype=@admin";
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
                    MainWindow Dashboard = new MainWindow();
                    Dashboard.Show();
                    this.Close();
                }
                else if ((bool)checkbox2.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    query = "SELECT usertype FROM Login WHERE Username=@Username AND password=@password and usertype=@student";
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
                    Student stu = new Student();
                        stu.Show();
                    this.Close();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password are incorrect");
```

Comment: That doesn't look like C. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it, and set the correct language tag.

Comment: looks like C# to me, possibly even Winforms

Comment: it is c# but i press enter mistakenly before i add the # sorry for that

Comment: 1) It is not C code. 2) You should build a simple (compilable) example with a `main` making easier to reproduce your problems (for example structure definition such as SqlCommand are important to understand why a crash may occur and are missing), 3) You should explain what _"It doesn't work" mean. How should it work?

Comment: What error are you having exactly?

Comment: 'Log_in' does not contain a definition for 'checkbox1_Checked' and no extension method 'checkbox1_Checked' accepting a first argument of type 'Log_in' could be found @ChrisBD

Comment: If the error message point outs to lines of codes it's usually helpful to include the referenced codes in the question.

Comment: In Visual Studio, right now there's a message about the error in the Error List panel. If you *click* on it, it will take you straight to where it's called. You never include that code in your question, so we will never be able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is exactly, but this will cause you issues:

```
MainWindow Dashboard = new MainWindow();
Dashboard.Show();
this.Close();
```

Dashboard is local to your function and when `this.Close();` is called will go out of scope.

You should move it elsewhere so that it remains in scope once this Form is closed.

**edit**
From your latest comment:

> 'Log_in' does not contain a definition for 'checkbox1_Checked' and no extension method 'checkbox1_Checked' accepting a first argument of type 'Log_in' could be found

I suggest that you search for `checkbox1_Checked` in your code. It looks as if the compiler is looking for this, could it actually be called `checkbox1_CheckedChanged` or should it be `checkbox1.IsChecked`?

**edit**

Please search your entire solution (Find and Replace - Find In Files) for `checkbox1_Checked` it may be that the Form designer file has become corrupted e.g. `Log_in.Designer.cs` contains a line similar to `this.checkbox1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.checkbox1_Checked);`

Comment: i build the login page first the i tried to make into multi log in page but when i run the codes it says like "'Log_in' does not contain a definition for 'checkbox1_Checked' and no extension method 'checkbox1_Checked' accepting a first argument of type 'Log_in' could be found"" so it is not reading the USERTYPE that is my problem @ChrisBD

Comment: @matt Maybe consider updating the question with just what is USERTYPE and where does checkbox1_Checked is being called.

Comment: @ChirsBD i add the whole coding up check please

Comment: Okay I've edited my answer - please perform a Find in Files search on the whole solution for "checkbox1_Checked", supposing that double clicking the error in the output window doesn't take you to it.

Comment: there is no (checkbox1_Checked ) in the whole coding i try to find it through find in files but it says "" was not found "" ! .... let me ask you a question is this the right way to right the codes and tell to difference between the users ! i'm new in programming as you can tell .. should checkbox1_Checked  be declared before i use it in the if statement ?!  @ChrisBD